# How to protect Apache poi sxssf sheet with optional locking of features like autofilter

Tags: apache, apache-poi

Apache poi sxssf protect sheet with optional locking of features not available with 3.17, but the documentation shows otherwise.
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#lockAutoFilter-boolean-
Also, xssf sheet does have this feature. Is there a way to do this in sxssf sheet?

Comment: The documentation you linked is not the one for `apache poi` version `3.17` but is the one for the currently latest nightly build. So `apache poi` version `4.0.0` should have those features.

Comment: Hmm. I checked changelog for 4.0.0 , but couldn't find that change. However, on a second look , I could see that it was added as part of 3.17 beta-1. Now, since I cannot upgrade to java8 to use 4.0.0, I would use 3.17 beta-1

Comment: 3.17 came out after 3.17-beta1 so anything in beta1 should be in 3.17.

Comment: I couldn't find the source code for 3.17 anywhere online to verify.  It is a bit strange then that I couldn't find the corresponding methods  in my 3.17 Maven build.

Comment: Finally, I could find it https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.java?view=log&pathrev=1800147

Comment: https://github.com/apache/poi/tree/REL_3_17_FINAL